# What is correct method to encrypt and decrypt data in magento 2?

Tags: magento, magento2

I am creating **magento 2** custom module, where I am getting some data using API call. I need to store that data in my custom table. Before storage I need to encrypt that data. I think there is default encrypt function for that. I have used `Mage::helper('Mage_Core_Helper_Data')->encrypt($value)`. But no success.

Comment: Is this for Magento 1 or Magento 2? The example code is Magento 1 but you've tagged 2 in your question

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: my question is how to call function encrypt() in magento 2?

Comment: @kushalmehta, have you got how to encrypt/decrypt data in Magento 2, If yes can you share something.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it this way:

```
use Magento\Framework\Encryption\EncryptorInterface as Encryptor;
```

in the construct function :

```
$this->encryptor = $encryptor;
```

then call encrypt function to encrypt:

```
$encrypt = $this->encryptor->encrypt($data);
```

and to decrypt:

```
$decrypt = $this->encryptor->decrypt($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Default Magento, out of the box comes with functionality of encryption and decryption using EncryptorInterface class.
First of all, we need to define EncryptorInterface class as in our file

```
use Magento\Framework\Encryption\EncryptorInterface;
```

After that, we need to declare one variable inside our class.

```
protected $encryptor;
```

Now we have to create constructor of class.

```
$this->encryptor = $encryptor;
```

After that, we need to call encrypt function to encrypt the given information

```
$id='magecomp';
$encrypt = $this->encryptor->encrypt($id);
```

and to decrypt that information, we simply need to write following line.

```
$decrypt = $this->encryptor->decrypt($encrypt);
```

for more details follow below link,

https://magecomp.com/blog/use-encryption-decryption-magento-2/